# Why is my input bumping to the next line after the first one?

Tags: html, css

I have been playing with this trying to get a layout i like for this form.. and i thought i had something i liked, but after the first row of input the formatting gets messed up and im not sure what im doing wrong..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Add Company</title>
<style>
    /* Style for add_client form */
    fieldset#add_field {
        width:830px;
    }

    fieldset#Basic_Info, fieldset#Address {
        width: 46%;
        float:left;
    }

    fieldset lebel {
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
    }

    fieldset label, label span { 
        display: block; 
        padding-bottom: .25em;
    }

    fieldset#add_field span {
        float: left;
        text-align: right;
        width: 44%;
    }

    fieldset#add_field input {
        float: right;
        width: 44%;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
    }

    fieldset#add_field select {
        float: right;
        width: 45%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='content'>
    <fieldset id='add_field'>
        <legend>Add Company</legend>

        <fieldset id='Basic_Info'>
            <legend>Basic Info</legend>

            <label for="name"><span>Company Name</span><input id="name" /></label>
            <label for="phone"><span>Phone Number</span><input id="phone" /></label>
            <label for="status"><span>Status</span>
                <select id='status'>
                    <option>1. Lead</option>
                    <option>2. Initial Contact</option>
                    <option>3. Negotiation</option>
                    <option>4. Client</option>
                    <option>5. Previous Client</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id='Address'>
            <legend>Address</legend>

            <label for="county"><span>Street Address</span><input id="county" /></label>
            <label for="city"><span>City</span><input id="city" /></label>
        </fieldset>

    </fieldset> 
    <input style='margin-top: 20px;' type="submit" value="Submit" id='jqxSubmitButton' />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please try to it explain it a bit more in detail - everything looks right to me when I try your code http://dabblet.com/gist/3157403

Comment: @Ana see how phone number is between the two text inputs instead of to the left of the second one? There should be label text on the left and and input to the right of it on each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your CSS:

```
fieldset lebel {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}
```

`lebel` should be `label`. See if this fixes the float issues. (I had trouble copy/pasting your code. Try linking to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) setup next time)

Comment: Thank you very much.. I am so bad at spotting typos haha.